# use jquery to capture form data and post using ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

Newbie here. I am building an app in rails and I'm trying to use jquery to capture the values of multiple select boxes within a form. I've tried to simplify this down as much as possible.

**form html:**

```
<form action="/units" data-remote="true" id="add_form" method="post">

<select class="select_box" id="box_1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="select_box" id = "box_2"
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option selected="selected" value="3">3</option>
</select>

*... additional select boxes...*

<input disable_with="Loading..." name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

In my **application.js** I want to capture the selected value of each select box.

I've tried using `serialize()` but can't get it to work since the form is dynamically generated using javascript (i.e. is not part of the DOM when the page is initially loaded).

Since there a lot of form elements (~20) I want to avoid working through the form elements one-by-by to capture the data, e.g.

```
var val_1 = $("#box_1").find(":selected").val()
var val_2 = $("#box_2").find(":selected").val()
...
```

Is there some way I can capture all of the selected values of a given class of elements (i.e. .select_box) and store them in an array?

perhaps something along the lines of:

```
var form_data = $(".select_box").find(":selected").data()
```

or somehow loop through the elements of class `.select_box` ?

Just can't quite get my head around this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can get your relevant data:

```
var form_data = $(".select_box").find(":selected").map(function (index) {
            return ($(this))[0].value;
        });
```

and this is how you can convert it to JSON for sending to server:

```
JSON.stringify(form_data.get())
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data()` method is used to get the values of an element's `data` attributes.

You can use the `serialize()` method on the `form` element to retrieve the values of all elements within the form.

Or you can use the `val()` method to retrieve the value of each element.

i.e: `$("#textfield_id").val(); // gets the value of a textfield`

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that I can't use serialize... I have to cycle through the elements one by one and capture the values.. reason being is that the html form I am working with is dynamically generated using javascript, i.e. not part of the DOM when the page is loaded. hope that makes sense

Comment: I have a lot (~20) elements in the form so don't want to use val() to get the value for each one. Is there someway to get all of the values with a given class, i.e. .select_box ?

Comment: @user3711600 why is that a problem? once you add elements to the DOM with javascript, they become part of the DOM, and you can serialize them as if they were loaded with the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `serialize()` to serialize (as Kyle said) form data, and then post the form. Try this:

```
$.post( "yourPageUrl", $( "#add_form" ).serialize() );
```